# How to: script convertion from SRTM to 3D printable file?

Tags: dem, 3d, srtm, 3d-map

**Given a STRM3.tiff file** as input.

**How to convert this STRM.tiff file into a 3D printable file ?** which I may load into most 3D printers' sofwares.

My objective is to print some terran, lunar, or martian reliefs with a basic 3D printer.

Gdal approach, QGis, or other welcome. Scriptic / terminal approach favored.

Comment: What format does your 3D printer use?

Answer (score 1):

You may import the SRTM map into GRASS GIS, then convert it to voxels. For details see on http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Help_with_3D the section "2 Raster 3D Volumes (voxels)". To verify prior to 3D printing, consider an export into VTK format and a visual check with Paraview (see [GRASS and Paraview](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Paraview#2D.2F3D_Raster.2Fvoxel_export)). Here some hints on [3D voxel export](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Help_with_3D#Visualization_Tools_and_export), eventially it depends on what your 3D printer accepts.